# populating a fixed dimensions div with photos

Tags: javascript, math, image-gallery, photo-gallery, sprite-sheet

I'm really struggling with this.
I have a div with fixed dimensions (height and width).
I have an undetermined number of photos I want to fill the div with. They vary in dimensions. They can be resized as long as they keep their aspect ratio.
I'd like to get some ideas to what would be the best way to populate the div so that ideally all the photos fit in it and there's the least "white space" or gaps. I'd actually prefer minimal "leaks" outside the div over gaps.
I've tried many alleys so far (masonry, google+ style, simple css) but I can't come up with a satisfying solution.

Edit:
After some more research, I found that what I'm looking for is actually really close to a [packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem#Packing_squares), but the closest problem I found was 'packing different rectangles in a rectangle', and I need a solution to 'packing different rectangles in a rectangle *of a specific aspect ratio*.

Any math geniuses out there?

Comment: might help to make a jsfiddle and post some code

Comment: The closest I got to solving this was with Ed Lea's 'collagePlus', but it only aligns photos to the width, not the height: http://jsfiddle.net/yjJ8z/9/

Comment: Still interested in the problem?

Answer (score 0):

this is what I use..

HTML:

```
<img id="myImage" src="" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%" />
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("myImage").src = imageName;
```

hope it helps... :)

Comment: This HTML is invalid.